# How to populate data from one sheet to another by making a list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, range, validation

I am trying to populate data from one sheet to another. On one sheet I have a bunch of different salespeople separated by activity for each month. I want to make a list on another sheet whereby if you select a specific salesperson, only their data is summarized, and then possibly add another filter by location.

Here is a picture of how my data is displayed. You can see I have locations at the top by the name of the salesperson, and this is only for September.

[image: Excel data example]

Comment: could dynamic ranges & data validating help in any way?

Answer (score -1):

Vlookups could do the trick. So could Pivot tables.

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit more on that? thx